# O Python parou de funcionar, mas acho que é algo no código

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter

Já fiz uma pergunta anteriormente sobre este projeto... Mas enfim, trabalhei nele e adicionei a classe Menu, que é uma classe filha da classe Janelas.
Segue o código do arquivo codigo_principal.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from janela import *

menu=Menu(["Roboto",10],"LavenderBlush",[1,40],('250x170'),"MENU")
```

Agora o arquivo janela.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from criar_widgets import *

class Janelas:
    def __init__(self,fonte,fundo,titulo):
        #Esta é a variável da janela mãe
        self.root = Tk()

        #Esta é a cor de fundo da janela
        self.root["bg"]=fundo

        #Este é o título
        self.titulo=Criar_Label_Titulo(self.root,titulo,fonte,fundo)

        return

class Menu(Janelas):
    def __init__(self,fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo):
        super().__init__(fonte,fundo,titulo)

        abaixar,alinhar=30,70

        self.bt_login=Criar_Button(self.root,"LOGIN",fonte,fundo,lambda:Autenticar(self.root, fonte, fundo, xy,"250x170","LOGIN",False))

        self.bt_cadastrar=Criar_Button(self.root,"CADASTRO",fonte,fundo,lambda:Cadastro(self.root,fonte, fundo,xy,"400x200","CADASTRO",False))

class Autenticar(Janelas):
    def __init__(self,janela_antiga,fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo):

        janela_antiga.destroy()

        super().__init__(fonte,fundo,titulo)

        abaixar,alinhar=30,70

        self.user=Criar_Label(self.root,"USUÁRIO",xy[0],xy[1],fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_user=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+alinhar,xy[1],fonte,False)

        #Label e entrada da senha respectivamente
        self.senha=Criar_Label(self.root,"SENHA",xy[0],xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_senha=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+alinhar,xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,True)

        #Botão que fará a mudança para uma nova tela
        self.botao=Criar_Button(self.root,"INSERIR NOME",fonte,fundo,lambda:Autenticar.login(self.root, self.entrar_user.entry.get(), self.entrar_senha.entry.get()))

        #Este é o tamanho da janela
        self.root.geometry(tela)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def login(root,usuario,senha):
        if usuario == "" and senha == "":
            #print("Tudo certo, podemos fazer a próxima janela")
            nova_janela=Cadastrar(root,["Roboto",10],"LavenderBlush",[1,40],('400x200'),"AUTENTICAR",False)

class Cadastrar(Janelas):
    def __init__(self,janela_antiga,fonte,fundo,xy,tela,titulo):
        #Adeus janela  antiga
        janela_antiga.destroy()

        #olá janela nova
        super().__init__(fonte,fundo,titulo)

        #As variáveis a seguir serão usadas para alinhar e abaixar cada widget
        abaixar,alinhar=30,150

        #Label e entrada do nome
        self.nome=Criar_Label(self.root,"NOME",xy[0],xy[1],fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_nome=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+alinhar,xy[1],fonte,False)

        self.genero=Criar_Label(self.root,"GÊNERO",xy[0],xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_genero=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+alinhar,xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,False)

        #Abaixar widgets mais 30 pixels
        abaixar+=30

        self.data_nascimento=Criar_Label(self.root,"DATA NASCIMENTO",xy[0],xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_data_nascimento=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+alinhar,xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,False)

        #Abaixar widgets mais 30 pixels
        abaixar+=30

        self.idade=Criar_Label(self.root,"IDADE",xy[0],xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,fundo)
        self.entrar_idade=Criar_Entry(self.root,xy[0]+alinhar,xy[1]+abaixar,fonte,False)

        self.botao_cadastrar=Criar_Button(self.root,"CADASTRAR",fonte,fundo,Cadastrar.salvar)

        self.root.geometry(tela)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def salvar():
        print("O botao funciona!!!")
```

E por último o arquivo criar_widgets.py (este nem encostei ultimamente, acho que o erro não vem daqui):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *

class Criar_Label:
    def __init__(self,root,texto,abcissa,ordenada,fonte,fundo):
         self.label=Label(root)
         self.label["text"]=texto
         self.label["font"]=fonte
         self.label["bg"]=fundo
         self.label.place(x=abcissa,y=ordenada)

#Será que deveríamos fazer polimorfismo aqui e fazer da classe Criar_Label a classe mãe?
class Criar_Label_Titulo:
    def __init__(self,root2,texto,fonte,fundo):
         self.titulo=Label(root2)
         self.titulo["text"]=texto
         self.titulo["font"]=fonte
         self.titulo["bg"]=fundo
         self.titulo.pack()

class Criar_Entry:
    def __init__(self,root2,abcissa,ordenada,fonte,segredo):
         self.entry=Entry(root2,font=fonte)
         self.entry.place(x=abcissa,y=ordenada)
         if segredo:
             self.entry["show"]="*"

class Criar_Button:
    def __init__(self,root2,texto,fonte,fundo,comando):
         self.button=Button(root2)
         self.button["text"]=texto
         self.button["font"]=fonte
         self.button["bg"]=fundo
         self.button["command"]=comando

         self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Não retorna ero e nem nada, apenas não roda o script, visto que funcionava perfeitamente antes n pode ser nada no sistema(até por que não mexi no sistema nesse meio tempo).

O sistema operacional utilizado por mim é o "Xubuntu Linux version 5.0.0-36-generic"
Print do meu terminal executando o arquivo e mostrando que ele está lá:

[image: Print do meu terminal executando o arquivo e mostrando que ele está lá]

Eu realmente acredito que não se trata do sistema operacional ou má instalação, apenas uma mudança no código que deve ter sido maliciosa e que n~ao consigo encontrar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está correto, e realmente não está gerando exceção, acontece que em momento algum você chamou o método `mainloop`, com isso você cria toda a interface e acaba não exibindo ela, e o programa encerra normalmente, afinal não há mais código pra ser executado.

Você pode optar por algumas modificações, uma delas seria você utilizar da propriedade root que `Menu` herda de `Janelas` e chamar o método `mainloop`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from janela import *

menu=Menu(["Roboto",10],"LavenderBlush",[1,40],('250x170'),"MENU")
menu.root.mainloop()
```

Também é possível criar um método que acesse essa propriedade e exiba a dialog, criando na classe Janelas, todas as que herdam já teriam acesso, por exemplo:

```
def show(self):
    self.root.mainloop()
```

Se você reparar, nas classes `Cadastrar` e `Autenticar`, você chamou esse método logo no `__init__`, ou seja, você pode fazer o mesmo na classe `Menu`:

```
self.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Funcionou!!!! Obrigado